# How to fix 'webroot/ not found on this server' for cakephp application accessed via https?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, https

I have a cakephp 3.5.x application running and online.

Accessing the page with **http**://www.xy.de/intern/users/login everything works fine.

Accessing the page with **https**://www.xy.de/intern/users/login I get following error:

> The requested address '/webroot/users/login'
>   was not found on this server.

How can I configure the application so that https will work?

I tried a lot with changing the .htaccess files but until now nothing worked.

My current .htaccess files look like this:

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In cakephp logs I get following error:

```
Error: [Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingControllerException] Controller class Webroot could not be found.
    Request URL: /webroot/users/login
    Stack Trace:
    #0 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ControllerFactory.php(38): Cake\Http\ControllerFactory->missingController(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest))
    #1 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php(90): Cake\Http\ControllerFactory->create(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
    #2 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php(103): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
    #3 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Http\BaseApplication->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
    #4 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php(107): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
    #5 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
    #6 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php(88): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
    #7 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
    #8 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php(95): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
    #9 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
    #10 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(51): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
    #11 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php(81): Cake\Http\Runner->run(Object(Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue), Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
    #12 webroot/index.php(40): Cake\Http\Server->run()
    #13 {main}
```

The application is hosted on strato.de so I have no fully control about the server settings.

I also contacted the helpline of strato and got the answer that my goal was technical too challenging for them.

All other pages in same web space which are not using cakephp work fine with https.

Comparing $_SERVER values from webroot/index.php show me following results:

http:

```
"SCRIPT_URL":"/intern/users/login",
"SCRIPT_URI":"http://www.xy.de/intern/users/login",
"REQUEST_URI":"/intern/users/login",
```

https:

```
"SCRIPT_URL":"/intern/webroot/users/login",
"SCRIPT_URI":"https://www.xy.de/intern/webroot/users/login",
"REQUEST_URI":"/intern/webroot/users/login",
```

the same:

```
"PHP_SELF":"/intern/webroot/index.php",
```

But I don't know where these differences come from and how to solve it.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Also no luck to fix it. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Did you enabled SSL at control panel?

Comment: Which control panel do you mean? I added the comment to my question, that all other pages with no cakephp in same web space work fine with https. So in general ssl seems to be fine. Just not with cakephp.

Comment: Compare the contents of `$_SERVER` in the HTTP and HTTPS environments.

Comment: I compared the contents of $_SERVER. I didn't saw any suspicious differences: [HTTPS] = on was of course only for https environment. [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive, [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0 were only for http environment. And [SERVER_PORT] and [REMOTE_PORT] were different for both environments. Everything else was the same.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? Just asking becase it's `$_SERVER` where CakePHP obtains the information from for building the request target URL (against which the routes are being tested), specifically `PATH_INFO`, `PHP_SELF`, and `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, and the fact that `/webroot` is in the URL indicates there's something wrong. Have you tested it with a new, clean app to rule out possible custom code/config in your app causing this? The `App.base`, `App.webroot`, and `App.baseUrl` config settings are involved in building the request target URL too.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I will test it with a new app, that's a good idea. And regarding $_SERVER: What is the best way to check it? I added a new php file in the webroot folder (parent folder it was not accessible because of rewrite) which prints out the content of $_SERVER. But now I'm not sure if e.g. PHP_SELF has the relevant info because it is of course the new php file path inside webroot.

Comment: You can use the apps `webroot/index.php` file, it's the entry point for all requests.

Comment: Okay, now I logged the $_SERVER values from webroot/index.php. You were right, there are different paths. I added the results at the end of the question. But how to solve this?

Comment: Generally this looks some kind of server misconfiguration to me, nothing I personally could really help with from here. Are you sure the URL that you are visiting is `www.xy.de/users/login`? From those values it looks like you are requesting `www.xy.de/intern/users/login`, ie as if your app is installed in the public subdirectory `intern`? This could be a possible rewrite related issue then, as the `/intern/webroot/users/login` value is what I would expect to be set as `REDIRECT_URL`, not as `REQUEST_URI`, but I'm just shooting in the dark here. You may want to contact your hoster again.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I also have the feeling, that some server configuration of the hoster is here the problem, but before I can contact them again I think I need a clue where exactly the problem is. You are right in the beginning I tried to simplify the question, but yes it is a webspace with a lot of different applications and only in `/intern` the cakephp app is installed. I just don't understand the difference between http and https. Because for http rewriting the path seems to be fine.

Comment: I guess there's lots of possible things that could cause this. Maybe try [**serverfault**](https://serverfault.com) and make this purely about rewrite usage and `REQUEST_URI` being different depending on the environment, maybe some server expert has an idea what could cause this.